# Performing image rectification to a jpeg using ERDAS Imagine

Tags: erdas-imagine

I am trying to rectify some images on ERDAS Imagine. These images are jpegs. They have no projection data. How do I do this?

Comment: What kind of images you have? Map? Screenshot? Aerials??  And start thinking about the projection you like to have.

Answer (score 1):

A Google search for `image rectification erdas` turns up a number of useful looking tutorials, as well as the [help file](ftp://ftp.ecn.purdue.edu/jshan/86/help/html/rectification/rectification.htm).

Image rectification requires:

1. the raw image (in this case, the jpegs)
2. ground control points

The raw image doesn't need to have any projection data (indeed, I'd say *shouldn't have*, because if it's already georeferenced then a projection transform is the way to go).

> A ground control point is a location within an image for which the map
>   coordinates are known. To be useful in rectification, the coordinates
>   of a GCP must be known in the system to which the data are being
>   rectified (e.g. lat/lon).

It's possible to get GCP data in the field with a GPS, but I have more frequently referenced imagery to existing vector or raster data (that *does* have an associated projection). You need to identify common locations in both the reference and input data, and the number of required GCPs depends on the type of transformation you'll be doing -- translation, rotation, warping, etc.